# Creating AMQ network of broker clusters on JBoss Fuse 6.2, without fabric

Tags: activemq-classic, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I want to create (2) broker clusters connected by network of brokers in JBoss Fuse 6.2; each cluster has 2 master/slave pairs.

It's a small cluster, so we don't intend to use Fabric/Zookeeper; everything will be statically configured, no auto discovery.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to use fabric profiles to build the topology, but
  avoid using fabric at runtime?
- Can we use Git, or something similar, for centrally managing container config files, again, without fabric?

We tried creating profiles using `fabric:mq-create`, but the command is not available unless a fabric is first created, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fabric profiles requires using fabric. You can use git to store files, but you cannot have JBoss Fuse automatic use it such as it does with fabric. You would need to use git manually.

The AMQ broker in JBoss Fuse is just standard Apache ActiveMQ so you can configure it manually/static as a network of brokers. It just not very easy to do if you haven't done that before.

See the JBoss A-MQ documentation as that covers the broker: http://www.jboss.org/products/amq/overview/

for example at: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.2/html/Using_Networks_of_Brokers/index.html

Comment: To confirm what you're saying, I can't use `fabric:` commands or profiles, correct? I'm assuming I can use `config:` commands to configure container properties, but `git` must be used manually for storing/managing configuration across remote containers. Is that accurate? Do you know where I can find master/slave, NoB full mesh example?

Comment: I suggest to see the JBoss A-MQ documentation.

Comment: I'm asking about AMQ config in Fuse, not AMQ standalone; just looking for confirmation on my last question to avoid going down wrong path.

Comment: config is for osgi config admin, eg the .cfg / pid files. Yeah you can use config to edit those. Its a karaf command. The JBoss A-MQ docs should cover it too as A-MQ runs inside Karaf just like JBoss Fuse.